# How should one distribute b2b app, which uses VOIP flag to stay always connected

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, voip, enterprise, b2b

I have a b2b app, which uses VOIP flag to stay always connected.

The best way might be to implement APNS support in app. But I dont want to change server side, so im looking for alternates.

Possible alternates are

**1. B2b Apps**

I can publish my app as [b2b](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/)

1. While submitting I dont see b2b app option (probably because tax info is missing)
2. My App is free, but for my customer to download my app has to purchase Volume purchase program. my custom will have to pay?

**2. Enterprise Account**

1. How to distribute app through [enterprise account](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_Wireless_Enterprise_App_Distribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) ?
2. Do I need to have my customer's UDID?

Please suggest the best possible way to distribute my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You yourself cannot get an Enterprise account (or rather, SHOULD not, if it's not your organization running the app).  Your client/the company needs to register for it.
2. With an Enterprise account, you can distribute apps without the UDID.  An Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile allows the app to be installed on an arbitrary number of devices, just like an App Store Distribution Provisioning Profile.  However, Apps signed with an Enterprise Distribution Provisioning Profile cannot be distributed on the App Store, and vice versa.

Note that registering for an Enterprise account is a bit more of a PITA than the regular developer account. For specific requirements, see: https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Edit:
It doesn't have to be paid, it can be free, but your customer will have to be part of the Volume Purchase Program.  Apple's site: "You can offer custom apps for free or at any price tier you select. Once you identify your customers and release date, you’re all set." - source: https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/

Comment: thanks for the answer, Why do you think other options are worthy enough?

Comment: I'm sorry what do you mean by other options?

Comment: I've added references so that you can better understand about available options.

Comment: When you say B2B - do you mean that your client/company is going to provide/sell these apps to other companies? Or your client IS a company and wants to provide this app to its employees?

Comment: Yes our client is itself a company. I understand what b2b is, so I can say we fall in this category.

Comment: In that case I would go the B2B route but note that for B2B apps, all users have to be pre-approved. That is, you'll have to list out all the authorized users' iTunes accounts in iTunes Connect before they can download the app.

Comment: Just one confirmation, for a B2B app as per my understanding. My client has to purchase "Volume Purchase program" and it also means that my App cant be free. It has to be paid to be a b2b app.

Answer (score 1):

If the app is only for your customer, the best thing you can do is tell them they have to buy an enterprise account.
Then you build the app with their account and host the `.ipa` on a web server only they can access.

Comment: For Enterprise account, our customers will have to pay? We want to distribute app free.

Comment: Yes, they have to pay the enterprise license, it's $300/year, but this way you haven't app store restrictions and only your customer can download the app.

Comment: AFAIK For enterprise account only developer has to buy 299$ account. And then developer can distribute app within the company (bound by license).

People who use your app, only need ipa and a valid certificate to install. I guess testflighapp works the same way.

Comment: Yes, only one person have to buy it, but they (your customer) should buy it, not you. If you aren't an enterprise you can't buy that license, because apple will require a DUNs number.

Comment: Cool So both answers are saying same thing.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to send them the certificate, you just need the .ipa and a .plist (it can be generated when you export the .ipa if you check the save for enterprise) and then upload both to a webserver and add a link to the .plis <a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=http://yourserver.com/your.plist">Install app</a>. Or you can use testflight and they will handle it for you.